# is it possible to connect android mobile app , wifi router and a wifi device?

Tags: android

i'm trying to establish a communication between android mobile app , wifi router and a wifi device how can i do it?

here wifi device is home built and it is connected to the router and both are static(router and device) only the android mobile is roaming .

EX: when you send a msg through whatsapp first it goes to whatsap server --> router(identifing ur ip addr) --> 2nd android device .

here is there any way to remove/replace with any other thing intermediate server so that i can send signal to my home built wifi device via router sitting anywhere in the country .

suggestions are accepted.

Thanks.

MORE INFO: message is nothing but ON/OFF signal of one or more divice.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about the size of the data you want to send. Messages or Streams? Interactive or batched?

Comment: MORE INFO: message is nothing but more like a ON/OFF signal of one or more divice

Comment: Ok. And how programmable is the wifi device?

Comment: that device only receives signal from the mobile and accordingly turn switches ON or OFF